# How can I restart a Ruby program?

Tags: ruby, monitoring

I'm running a ruby program for a personal project, and because it takes around 20 hours to finish the execution I want to "save the state" of the program every hour or so, in case there is power outage in my building.

I want to be able to restart the execution using the last "saved state" of the program. But I don't know if there is tool for doing that or if have to hard code the entire thing my self.

Comment: Genetic algorithms

Comment: What form does the "saved state" take?

Comment: Save the state of all the variables, and resume the execution using that saved state

Comment: Why in the world you would use ruby for such complex thing? You better use some super computer or at least buy you a power saver. LOL. upvoted.

Comment: My intention is to teach college studens about genetic algorithms, because ruby language is so easy to read (compare to C/C++) I chose that one, but dimensionality of the problem is more troublesome than I thought.

Comment: Leaving aside the time to save/recover, you probably want to look at Marshal: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Marshal.html.

Comment: You would then want to ```Marshal.load()``` or ```Marhsal.restore()```.

Comment: To be clear: you save the state with ```Marshal.dump()```, and restore with those.

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the state you have to save, a way to do this is saving a JSON string with all needed stated. At restart you'd just need to read it, put everything in the correct place and go ahead with your processing.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida: The one advantage ```Marshal.dump()/.restore``` has over JSON is storage density, and thus load time (depending on the data/implementation, the time to create objects from the raw data is generally similar, but the read time from the disk can be very different if you have data in binary form).

Comment: @DerrellDurrett, thanks for the explanation. I'll read a bit more about Marshal.dump(). Never used it, 'cause I never had to store this much information. For small block, JSON is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Comments into an answer.)

You'll probably want to use `Marshal[1]`. To save state, you `dump()`, and to restore state you either `load()` or `restore()`. The details of the process are going to strongly depend on the way the objects are interconnected, and the amount of data you are saving. If the data are small enough, you can even use JSON, and forgo `Marshal`.

You may have to experiment with the best choice for ***how*** to `dump()/load()` your data, because if you have one over-arching object loading all of that data into memory can really bog you down (even with an enormous amount of memory available to you). You may instead need to break that monolith into many smaller objects that are individually marshalled, and then marshal their container.